What determines a the potential difference of a battery?
From what I know a battery works by moving electrons through the circuit due to the chemical potential difference between the terminals , Here I have two questions

How do we calculate the potential difference of a battery ,in electrostatic potential it's calculated by taking the negative integral of E.ds so how does this compare to the battery as I've heard multiple times that comparing batteries to electrostatics is misleading

Is the electric field constant around the circuit? , If it's then how can there be a potential difference between the terminals anyway I mean for it be constant at every point the positive terminal and negative terminal field must add up to the same value meaning that near the terminals the field is still constant but in a different direction which just means that the potentials will cancel.


excuse me if I am mistaken as I am finding a hard time with this problem.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235038/2451

If part of your question is asking what determines the open-circuit voltage of a battery, then the chemistry stackexchange site might be a better place to ask for that detail.

See https://en-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Redox?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&x_tr_pto=sc  ; and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_cell (Open-circuit voltage 1.1018 V )I made one myself when I was a student with the paraffin paper of a capacitor for $SO{4}^{2-}$ ions...

the voltage generated by a cell depends on how much work gets released when an atom gives up an electron and passes it to a dissimilar atom. this is covered in the field of electrochemistry, about which whole libraries of books have been written. Simplified versions of electrochemistry form the basis of corrosion science.
